# python error in opening file (codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3), i use spyder

Tags: python, urllib, spyder

I'm still starting with python and got stuck with this error and have no idea what to do, I use spyder :

```
  File "C:\Users\Win8.1\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2963, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)

  File "<ipython-input-26-d3792eadd9d7>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/Win8.1/Documents/Python Scripts/ipnd-starter-code-master/stage_3/lesson_3.3_classes/c_profanity_editor/check_profanity.py', wdir='C:/Users/Win8.1/Documents/Python Scripts/ipnd-starter-code-master/stage_3/lesson_3.3_classes/c_profanity_editor')

  File "C:\Users\Win8.1\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 705, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\Win8.1\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/Win8.1/Documents/Python Scripts/ipnd-starter-code-master/stage_3/lesson_3.3_classes/c_profanity_editor/check_profanity.py", line 18
    quotes = open("C:\Users\Win8.1\Documents\Python Scripts\ipnd-starter-code-master\stage_3\lesson_3.3_classes\c_profanity_editor\movies_quotes.txt")
                 ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

code:

```
     import urllib
     def read_text():
         quotes = open("C:\Users\Win8.1\Documents\Python Scripts\ipnd- 
         starter-code- 
    master\stage_3\lesson_3.3_classes\c_profanity_editor\movies_quotes.txt")
contents_of_file = quotes.read()
print(contents_of_file)

     read_text()
```

mind the indentation and my ignorance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using spyder on a windows os your input string should contain double slash *'\'*, like this:

```
"C:\\Users\\Win8.1\\Documents\\Python Scripts\\ipnd-starter-code- 
    master\\stage_3\\lesson_3.3_classes\\c_profanity_editor\\movies_quotes.txt"
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the backslash `\` to `\\` in the filename, unless you use a raw string.